# SOAP::Lite complains about "Can't use 'defined(%hash)'"

Tags: perl, soaplite, perl5.30

While running the perl which is using SOAP::LITE module it is giving below error

```
Can't use 'defined(%hash)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /Library/Perl/5.30/SOAP/Lite.pm line 466.
```

Perl Version: 5.30

How to resolve this error

Comment: That's not in the current source code. https://metacpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite/source/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm#L466

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're seeing the combination of a couple of really old pieces of software:

- `defined %hash` was deprecated in [Perl 5.6.0](https://metacpan.org/dist/perl/view/pod/perl56delta.pod) (in March 2000) and has thrown a fatal error since [Perl 5.22.0](https://metacpan.org/dist/perl/view/pod/perl5220delta.pod#defined(@array)-and-defined(%25hash)-are-now-fatal-errors) (in June 2015)
- SOAP::Lite fixed that syntax in [version 0.713](https://metacpan.org/release/PHRED/SOAP-Lite-1.27/source/Changes) (in August 2011)

So the fix is to update your software!

Comment: Thanks Dave it resolved the issue

Comment: @SomyaChawla [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean "SOAP::Lite", not "SOAP::LITE". If so, you're not using the latest, and upgrading would surely fix this.

From the change log, it Looks like it was fixed in 0.713 back in 2011. That's over a decade ago!